# Continued Fractions to calculate at-bats

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Using Continued fractions and having a batting average of .3085443, guess how many at-bats the player had.

Any tips or solutions so I can solve this problem? Currently I am reading about continued fractions, but I don't see the correct approach to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the essential facts about continued fractions is that their convergents give the best possible rational approximations to irrational numbers; also, the best possible approximations with small denominators to a rational number with a large denominator.  The very best approximations are found by truncating the continued fraction just before a particularly large partial quotient.

So, the batting average is
$$0.3085443=\frac{3085443}{10000000}\ .$$
If we take this literally, the player will have had $3085443$ successes from $10000000$ times at bat (or perhaps even $6170886$ from $20000000$, etc).  This doesn't seem likely.  So we assume that the number of times at bat was actually smaller, and the given decimal is a rounded number.  We use continued fractions to work out the details.  We can calculate
$$0.3085443=\frac1{3+\displaystyle\frac1{4+\displaystyle\frac1{6+\displaystyle\frac1{1+\displaystyle\frac1{2+\displaystyle\frac1{1+\displaystyle\frac1{1+\displaystyle\frac1{658+\cdots}}}}}}}}$$
The first convergent is $\frac13$, meaning one success from three times at bat.  This is clearly not right as the average would have been rounded to $0.3333333$ not $0.3085443$.  The next convergent is
$$\frac1{3+\displaystyle\frac1{4}}=\frac4{13}=0.3076923\cdots$$
which is wrong for the same reason.  Keep trying until you find one that works.  I haven't gone any further but my guess would be that the answer is
$$\frac1{3+\displaystyle\frac1{4+\displaystyle\frac1{6+\displaystyle\frac1{1+\displaystyle\frac1{2+\displaystyle\frac1{1+\displaystyle\frac1{1}}}}}}}$$
found by truncating the continued fraction just before a particularly large partial quotient.

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my understanding of computation using continued fractions clearer as well! More helpful than the textbook.